# When I uninstall WhatsApp from Android device, would my chats'/msgs' data stay on device?

Tags: security, whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery, restore

so i made this stupid mistake of uninstalling whatsapp then giving away my phone without resting it to factory settings, so the other person now have my device, could he by a way or another retrieve my uninstalled whatsapp data? In other words, when we uninstall whatsapp, does all the data related to our whatsapp msgs and chats get deleted or do they stay in some form that could be retrieved? I don't know the guy very well so i don't trust him and i'd really appreciate to know what's what so maybe i could make a plan. Thank you.

Comment: If you have just uninstalled whatsapp and given phone to other person, then otherperson can have all data(whatsapp, google, gmail etc). Its recommended to reset before any sale options.

Comment: All your pictures and videos will still be on the phone

Comment: If your Google account is still active on that phone, then just go to 'lost phone' option online and format from there.

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate issues

- Factory reset was not done , so it's technically possible to retrieve data but this would involve sophisticated methods *not* in the reach of an average person
- As far as WhatsApp is concerned , when you uninstall , the data is  not accessible even on installing again since you need to authenticate the telephone number , which I presume it
  s with you. WhatsApp database is encrypted making it more difficult to retrieve messages but your WhatsApp *pictures, videos and audio* can be accessed

IMO, unless the other person is very savvy technically, it's not a cause for concern but then in future do remember to *encrypt your device and factory reset* to ensure that others cannot access your private data

Answer (score 1):

His gonna dowload his own WhatsApp then put in his own number,the back up of his WhatsApp will appear not yours,remember before going into WhatsApp after downloading it requires you to confirm your number,he cannot do that with someone else's number only his,so do not worry your WhatsApp info is safe and sound,they backed up on cloud somewhere,waiting for the rightful owner and his unique number.